# Why do two burners spark when I only turn on one?

Tags: gas, stove

I have a Thermador gas range model PRG304EH01. The right side has 2 burners (RF and RR) with igniters connected to their own spark module and microswitch. When I turn on one of the burners, another burner is also getting spark.

When the turned on burner ignites, the other one still continues sparking unless I turn the second burner ON.

The questions

1. Why and how, when burner has its own switch and spark module, the other burner is getting spark?
2. If that is by design, why doesn't the other burner stop sparking when the turned on burner ignites?
3. Could someone help me to find a service manual or, at least a wiring diagram for PRG304EH01?

Comment: There are these nifty things called "search engines" that allow you to rapidly search all the world's knowledge. Entering `Thermador PRG304EH01 service manual` into one, and hey, presto! https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1405358/Thermador-Prg304us.html

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sometimes that is really helpfull, but not in this particular case. You will not find in the manual neither the answer on my question, nor even at least a schematic or a wiring diagram, which might be helpful.... Still looking if anyone can really answer my question...

Comment: Then you should _tell_ us you've looked. If you hover over the down arrow, the pop-up text says "This question does not show any research effort", which your question doesn't... Beyond that, I'm sorry, I'm not the one to be able to help you - I know diddly squat about gas stoves.

Answer (score 1):

After I've got electric schematic from the customer I found that the only way of getting power for OTHER (than the one I'm turning ON) spark module was through the malfunctioning diodes. Those two right side Ignition modules are completely independent, and the only common part is the LED light which gets power from each (RF and RR) switches via its own diode, when they the either of the switches is ON. As soon as on of the switches is disconnected from the LED light, the problem is solved. To completely solve the problem (still having both RF and RR) connected to the Right LED indicator, that Indicator assy part (00617886) must be replaced.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).